# exporting gridview to word

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ms-word

```
     protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
            "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.doc");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
        }
```

this is my code in the .cs file what am trying to do is export a gridview to word file
but when i run the code it gives an error

**RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();**
 pls help

Comment: got the answer guys  EnableEventValidation ="false" just have to add this in the page directive

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from comment:

got the answer guys `EnableEventValidation ="false"` just have to add this in the page directive